# Django model stoped working when adding more models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a view in which the user can edit their profile everything worked fine and everything was being updated (biography, first_name, username, email and profile-picture) but now that I added a new app that contains three views in which the user can upload, delete and like posts, the user update sistem stoped working for some reason just the (update, email, first_name)still worked. The update view calls 2 models, User that lets you edit(name, username and email) and Profile that lets you edit(bio and change the profile pictures) it looks like when I added the upload, delete and like functions mentioned before, the whole Profile model "disapeared" even tho is there. The error I am getting is RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no profile.

models.py

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)
        connection = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
        follower = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        following = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    class Post(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        video = models.FileField(upload_to='clips', null=True, blank=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='imageuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='username')
        liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.text)

    LIKE_CHOICES = (
        ('Like', 'Like'),
        ('Unlike', 'Unlike'),
    )

    class Like(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, default='Like', max_length=10)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.post)
```

views.py

```
    def edit_profile(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            form1 = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
            if form.is_valid and form1.is_valid:
                form.save()
                form1.save()
                return redirect('profile')
        else:
            form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            form1 = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {
              'form': form,
              'form1': form1,
            }
        return render(request, 'profile-edit.html', args)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('<username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
        path('edit-profile', views.edit_profile, name='edit-profile'),

    ]
```

forms.py

```
    class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = (
                'first_name',
                'username',
                'email',
            )
            exclude = ('password',)

    class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = (
                'bio',
                'profile_pic',
            )
```

If you need to see more code please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Do you have a post_save signal that will create a user profile each time a new user is created? Or if you made your Profile model after your User model and you already had users, you will need to create profiles for them manually on the admin page.

Comment: @MeL a user profile is created automatically everytime there is a new user

Comment: @MeL The error happens just when I try to edit the profile page

Comment: I don't see the signal in your code, but you could try adding in your views before your if statement: profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

Comment: @MeL your code seems to make the profile work! just for asking what does the "comma" between profile and create mean?

Comment: @MeL another thing I fortgot to say that I am getting a no reverse at match error but the edits are saved let me add my urls.py so that you can help me please

Comment: That's great! It's just because the profile either already exists or must be created, so the result is a tuple.

Comment: @MeL I really appreciate that thankyou;)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in your urls file except that you're missing a forward slash. You might need to share your html as well, but this is already a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your views before the if statement:

```
profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

You need the ", created" since the result of `get_or_create` will be a tuple not an object - the profile either already exists or must be created.

For your new problem, change the following line:

```
form1 = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
```

to:

```
form1 = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
```

Comment: Hi Mel, I am having that same problem again but this time was because I added a follow sistem to my project

Comment: So basiclly I added the 3 last objects to the model which are connection, follower and following but every time I run the code, it returns `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'` in line `form1 = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)` please this problem has to stop.

Comment: Now you can see the 2 forms from the accounts app which are EditProfileForm that calls the User model and the UpdateProfileForm that calls the Profile model.

Comment: MeL it still returns the same error, you can check my complete code in these [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353214/how-to-edit-users-profile-page-on-django)